# How can I use all the selected values of a column, one by one, in another query?

Tags: oracle, select, oracle-11g, subquery

Use column values returned from the statement below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column_name) FROM Table1;
```

into the following query:

```
SELECT dif_col_1, 
       dif_col_2 
  FROM Table2 
 WHERE key_in_table = (SELECT key_in_table 
                         FROM Table3 
                        WHERE UPPER(some_column) LIKE '%each_value_from_the_first_query%');
```

Comment: Are you looking for `...Where upper(some_column) in (select distinct upper(column_name) from table1);`?

Comment: In my case, UPPER(some_column) like 'each....first_query' does not always match so its more like - UPPER(some_column) like '%each_value..first_query%'. What should be changed to achieve this match ?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **NOT** a function. Writing `distinct (column_name)` is exactly the same thing as `distinct column_name`

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from the inner query and work our way out. You want to return rows from `Table3` for which a column matches (using the `LIKE` operator) any column from `Table1`, right? I would use the [EXISTS](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exists.php) operator for that. We can reword your problem as "return all rows from `table3` for which there exists at least one matching row from `Table1`". Here's one implementation:

```
SELECT key_in_table 
FROM Table3 
WHERE EXISTS
(    
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table1
    WHERE UPPER(Table3.some_column) LIKE '%' || Table1.column_name || '%'
);
```

You can run that query separately so you can be satisfied that it returns the results that you're after. The final query is as simple as integrating that subquery into what you already had:

```
SELECT dif_col_1, dif_col_2
FROM Table2 
WHERE key_in_table = 
(
    SELECT key_in_table 
    FROM Table3 
    WHERE EXISTS
    (    
        SELECT 1
        FROM Table1
        WHERE UPPER(Table3.some_column) LIKE '%' || Table1.column_name || '%'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use your first query as a derived table and join it to `Table3` using the `LIKE` predicate in the joining condition:

```
SELECT
  dif_col_1,
  dif_col_2
FROM
  Table2
WHERE
  key_in_table IN
  (
    SELECT
      Table3.key_in_table
    FROM
      Table3
      INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT column_name AS column_name from Table1) t1
        ON UPPER(Table3.some_column) LIKE '%' || t1.column_name || t1.'%'
  )
;
```

Note the change of  `key_in_table = ...` to `key_in_table IN ...`. As the subquery is matching against a set of values, it can produce a set (multiple rows) of its own. Comparing a single value to a set of two or more values would produce an error in Oracle, hence using a different predicate (`IN`).